# Submit Form Button not run onclick () javascript function in Safari

Tags: javascript, forms, button, safari, submit

Submit form button not submitting and loses style in Safari 9 and plus.
It works on Chrome and Firefox. I´ve seen some posts with a similar problem but all the solutions presented did not work for me.

In JS I have one event handler onsubmit and one onclick function in the button to check if the fields are empty or not and that triggers a popup where the information is printed by the onsubmit event handler. Didn´t paste here the JS code that is quite huge...

Thank you:

Here is the link to the project:

https://github.com/carlosrbatalha/survey-saving-our-planet

The Code:

```
 HTML:

    <div class="outer-button">
    <button form="survey-form" id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" onclick='myFunction()'>Submit</button>
    </div>

    CSS:

        .outer-button {

      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      padding-bottom: 50px;
    }

#submit {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
  display: flex;

   border:none;
  -webkit-border:none;
  -webkit-border-radius:0px;
  -webkit-appearance:default-button;


  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  width: 100px;

  padding:10px;

  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-size: calc(9px + (21 - 9) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));  
  cursor: pointer; 
}

#submit:hover{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
  border: none;
  -webkit-border:none;
  -webkit-border-radius:0px;
  -webkit-appearance:default-button;
  }
```

Comment: Submit buttons shouldn't have `click` handlers set up on them. Instead, set up a `submit` handler for the `form`.

Comment: Where and what is `myFunction`?

Comment: I think you what you need is, on form submit event

Comment: Hello Doug the myFunction check if the fields are empty/correct and triggers a popup. There is also an event handler onsubmit that print the information in the popup.

Comment: Hello Jan. I have allready a onsubmit event it works on Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari...

Comment: Hello Scott.  I have an event onsubmit as well, I took out the onclick function but still doesen´t work. Safari does not check the required fields as well ...

Comment: Is it wrapped in a form tag?

Comment: No Yesthe Cia. It´s wrapped in a main ad div tags out of the form tag.